# Split a alphabetically sorted list into sublists based on alphabets in java

Tags: java, list

I have a sorted list in java, i just want to split this list into sublists based on the first alphabet at each index of list. For example
List contains

```
{
calculator,
catch,
doll,
elephant
}
```

i want the sublists as

```
{calculator,catch}
{doll}
{elephant}
```

I dont want to put 26 if statements, is there any efficient and correct way of doing this. The list is already sorted alphabetically.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to put 26 if statements. Just keep track off when the first letter of the word changes.

Comment: i have tried to make some logic on the paper but its not good enough @AnandUndavia, thats why i am looking for some reliable and efficient method of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of @SilverNak is good with Java-8, you can use this also if you are not using Java-8 :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String list[] = {"calculator", "catch", "doll", "elephant"};
    Map<Character, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> lst;
    for (String str : list) {
        //if the key exit then add str to your list else add a new element
        if (map.containsKey(str.charAt(0))) {
            map.get(str.charAt(0)).add(str);
        } else {
            lst = new ArrayList<>();
            lst.add(str);
            map.put(str.charAt(0), lst);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to put the list back into the map if you got it from there, it’s already in there.

Comment: thank you @OleV.V. i already change it, but i'm not about the else is there any other way?

Comment: If using Java 8, you could use `computeIfAbsent()`; but the point was, what do we do in an earlier Java version? I consider your code fine. I might just do the `get()` first. If I got null, create the `ArrayList` and put it in (no need for an `else` part). Finally unconditionally add the string to the list. Same number of lines, so it’s a matter of taste.

Answer (score 7):

You could use Java 8 Streams. Unfortunately, this method doesn't take advantage from the list being sorted already. `list` has to be the list containing your elements.

```
Map<Character, List<String>> collect =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(elem -> elem.charAt(0)));
```

Comment: list.Stream and Collectors is undefined, i am using jdk 1.6 and cant upgrade to jdk 1.8, because myEclipse have max option of jdk 1.7.

Comment: Could updating eclipse be a solution?

Comment: i cant update eclipse, i have to work in that environment. sorry :(, is there any solution with jdk 1.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a third-party library, [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) 7.x will work with Java 6.  Using Eclipse Collections `MutableList` you can call `groupBy` as follows:

```
MutableList<String> list = 
        Lists.mutable.with("calculator", "catch", "doll", "elephant");
Multimap<Character, String> multimap = 
        list.groupBy(StringFunctions.firstLetter());
System.out.println(multimap); 
// Prints {d=[doll], e=[elephant], c=[calculator, catch]}
```

If you need to use a `java.util.List` for the Strings, then you can use the `ListAdapter` class.

```
List<String> list =
        Arrays.asList("calculator", "catch", "doll", "elephant");
Multimap<Character, String> multimap =
        ListAdapter.adapt(list).groupBy(StringFunctions.firstLetter());
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.

```
private List<List<String>> subListOnFirstLetter(List<String> list) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    char first = list.get(0).charAt(0);
    List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String element : list) {
        char next = element.charAt(0);
        if (next != first) {
            result.add(subList);
            subList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            subList.add(element);
        }
        first = next;
    }
    return result;
}
```