# Java, partition a list with a condition

Tags: java

Say for example I have this list:

`[A, C, A, B, B, C, A]`

Is there a way in RxJava or other fancy code that turns it into a list of sorted list?

`[[A, A, A], [B, B], [C, C]]`

The requirement of grouping is each object inside the list as a date, I want to sort and group them by date

Comment: Not really a dublicate. I do not know why somebody would close this.

Comment: Do you want all elements in inside list to be exactly same or just the first character as same? What is the requirement for the grouping?

Comment: @pdrersin: it's certainly close enough. Just change the `Collectors.groupingBy(...)` classification function.

Comment: please see the update, I want the list to be sorted and grouped by date

Comment: Here is a solution :  

```List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

  list.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "B"));
  List<List<String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
  Collections.sort(list);
  int head =0;
  for (int i = 1; i < list.size() ; i++) {
   if (!list.get(i).equals(list.get(i-1))) newList.add(list.subList(head, head=i));
  }
  System.out.println(newList);```

Comment: The linked question contains enough infoemation. But please use [the Java 8 Streams method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42692670/507738).